# 桜桜ーいざや and ゆかん meanings

Tags: song-lyrics, classical-japanese

In　桜桜 what do "いざや" and "見に行かん" mean, or rather *why* do they mean what they mean. 
I've never heard a term like いざや, and I've never seen 行く written as ゆく, nor have I seen an あん  ending unless it was going to be あない.

Comment: Please provide quoted examples and a less convoluted question. thanks

Comment: The song title is usually spelled in hiragana, and you can find a perfectly good translation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakura_Sakura).

Answer (score 4):

Kohsuke Kawaguchi already answered your question, but I want to add a little bit of detail about ゆかん.

You wrote the following:

> nor have I seen an an ending unless it was going to be あない.

This stem of the verb is called the [未然形{みぜんけい}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AA%E7%84%B6%E5%BD%A2) in traditional Japanese grammar, and several things can attach to it besides the auxiliary [ない](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=114427600000).  Historically, there was an auxiliary called [む](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%80), and this is what the ん represents in ゆかん in this song.

As an aside, the modern auxiliary [う](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%86&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=11&index=101437500000) (as in だろう) is derived from む, and it attaches to the 未然形{みぜんけい} as well, so you'd expect a form like ゆかう.  However, over time the pronunciation of the vowels changed from /au/ to /o:/, and the modern Japanese spelling was changed to ゆこう to reflect this change.  (Although it only partially reflects it, since the う is part of the long vowel /o:/.  I wonder why they didn't change the spelling of う as well!)

Back on topic, an "an" ending can also represent the 未然形{みぜんけい} plus the negative auxiliary [ぬ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AC&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=115059700000), which functions much like the auxiliary ない.  (See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235/1478) for some discussion.)  Since this ぬ can be contracted to ん, you'll see forms like 知らん and いかん.  (In fact, this is also the ん in ありません.)

If you see an ending like this in modern Japanese, it's much more likely to be the negator ぬ than the historical auxiliary む, because the latter isn't part of the modern language.  (Except, I think, in a few fossilized expressions like [言わんばかり](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2767/1478).)

Answer (score 2):

いざ is an older expression that means "let us", and や is adding an emphasis.

As a Japanese I don't particularly feel odd that 行く is written as ゆく, especially because 行く has a risk of being read as いく.

～かん is another older expression that means "about to [do]".

I think the reason you feel odd about this whole sentence is that the whole thing uses expressions that are no longer actively in use.

Comment: Topic on `いざ`:　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5024/78